# How to read multivalue string field in custom solr function query?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am writing a custom solr function query for multivalue string field in solr.
Below is my code:

```
    import org.apache.solr.common.util.NamedList;
    import org.apache.solr.search.ValueSourceParser;
    import org.apache.solr.search.FunctionQParser;
    import org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError;
    import java.util.HashSet;

    import org.apache.lucene.queries.function.ValueSource;


    public class sortOnXSourceParser extends ValueSourceParser {
        public void init(NamedList namedList) {
        }

        public ValueSource parse(FunctionQParser fqp) throws SyntaxError {
            ValueSource source = fqp.parseValueSource();
            HashSet<Integer> topic_ids = new HashSet<Integer>();
            while(fqp.hasMoreArguments()){
                topic_ids.add(fqp.parseInt());
            }
            return new sortOnXSource(source, topic_ids);
        }
    }
```

My code compiles fine and when call is being made to this function
it throws an error at

```
ValueSource source = fqp.parseValueSource();
```

This function is being called for sorting the docs based on a multivalue field named x with this syntax

```
sortOnX(x, 309043) desc
```

and exception being shown in solr logs is

```
    2019-01-04 06:32:01.972 ERROR (qtp1573605215-22) [   x:emr-20181210] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Can't determine a Sort Order (asc or desc) in sort spec 'sortOnX(x, 309043) desc', pos=28
    at org.apache.solr.search.SortSpecParsing.parseSortSpecImpl(SortSpecParsing.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SortSpecParsing.parseSortSpec(SortSpecParsing.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getSortSpec(QParser.java:280)
```

This part of code was working fine when the field was multivalued=false but recently we had to make changes and made this a multivalued=true field.
**We want a way to access multivalue string field in custom function queries java code.**

```
My solr version is: 7.5.0
Lucene Version is: 7.5.0
Java version : 11.0.1 JVM 18.9
```

Comment: you want to access it in your custom code? or invoke sorting the way before?

Comment: I want to access it in my custom function query code as explained above in the code.
This field has multiple strings.

Comment: what is sortOnXSource? could you share this class?